# Why is Ex 3:10 in the reading of the Third Sunday in Lent (Year C) in German and French lectionary?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, mass, ordinary-form-of-the-mass

The first reading of the Third Sunday in Lent in Year C (today) is Ex 3, 1-8a.13-15. The new (Advent 2018) German lectionary includes also verse 10. The [French lectionary](https://www.aelf.org/2019-03-24/romain/messe) has the same.

The [old German lectionary](https://www.erzabtei-beuron.de/schott/register/fastenzeit/schott_anz/index.html?file=fastenzeit%2Fwoche3%2FSonntagC.htm), the [US lectionary](http://usccb.org/bible/readings/032419-yearc.cfm), the [Italian lectionary](https://www.chiesacattolica.it/liturgia-del-giorno/?data-liturgia=20190324), the [Brasil lectionary](http://liturgiadiaria.cnbb.org.br/app/user/user/UserView.php?ano=2019&mes=3&dia=24), the [Spanish lectionary](https://oracionyliturgia.archimadrid.org/2019/03/24/24-03-2019-domingo-de-la-3a-semana-de-cuaresma/), the current [Latin lectionary](http://www.ccwatershed.org/media/pdfs/14/05/05/11-44-20_0.pdf) (Ordo lectionem Missae. Editio typica altera 1981, p. 21 (PDF 67)) does not have this verse.

Where does this difference come frome?

I understand that the adddition makes sense. The mission to Moses should be mentioned before Moses says to God "But when I go to the Israelites ...".

Comment: Can I improve my question? Has the downvoter a reason for me?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable, well-stated question to me.

Comment: I may have found a legal basis for the adaption: "The Lectionary for Mass must be translated integrally in all its parts, including the Introduction. If the conference of bishops has judged it necessary and useful to add certain adaptations, these are to be incorporated after their confirmation by the Holy See.", Lectionary - General Introduction, no. 112 (https://www.liturgyoffice.org.uk/Resources/Rites/Lectionary.pdf) I suspect the acts of confirmation by the Holy See are not published.